# HTML5 Form elements and styles for mobile device

Tags: jquery, css, html, mobile

I am not using jQuery mobile for my mobile website, however i really like some of the form elements used.

I am struggling to find how to create the following form elements: -

1. Flip switch
2. Checkbox and radio button like jQuery mobile style
3. Drop down box from an image
4. The items labeled "font styling" and "layout view"

Here are the examples I need to recreate:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/forms/forms-all-mini.html

I know it uses HTML5 but Im at a loss on how to replicate the items on the above link WITHOUT using jQuery Mobile.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's done with background images and events using jquery. More specifically in the case of the "flip switch" its a ui-slider. In short you'd have to create your own plugins or code using jQuery or better yet in my opinion zepto.js.

Zepto is a nice library that's slimmed down for mobile platforms. The animations in particular for Zepto are nice on mobile platforms.

So where to start? Inspect the markup using your favorite dev tool in your browser. F-12 for chrome. Look at the divs, spans etc that each control you like creates. Note the css styling that's behind it. That will get you the look.

From there you'll have to wire up the jQuery/Zepto etc. Just being honest here but if you're asking how to create these its probably more work than you'll really want to invest.